# JBoss 7.1.1 changing JNDI binding in runtime

Tags: wildfly, jboss7.x, jndi, wildfly-9

In JBoss 7.1.1 in standalone mode all JNDI bindings are configured in standalone.xml file in jboss:domain:naming:1.1 subsystem. According to documentation standalone.xml cannot be modified when server is running. I've tried to use JBoss CLI but I don't know how to write/modify resource.

How to change value in JNDI without restarting jboss?

Answer (score 4):

Should help you: https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/JNDI+Reference

**Topic - Binding entries to JNDI:**

> An example standalone.xml might look like:
>
> ```
> <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:naming:1.1" >
>   <bindings>
>     <simple name="java:global/a" value="100" type="int" />
>     <object-factory name="java:global/b" module="com.acme" class="org.acme.MyObjectFactory" />
>     <lookup name="java:global/c" lookup="java:global/b" />
>  </bindings>
> </subsystem>
> ```

> To add these entries via the CLI:
>
> ```
> /subsystem=naming/binding=java\:global\/mybinding:add(binding-type=simple, type=long, value=1000)
> ```

> To see all all options that are taken by the add command (this can
> actually be used to get the description of any CLI command):
>
> ```
> /subsystem=naming/binding=*:read-operation-description(name=add)
> ```

*Have not tried, but i hope this helps!*

**UPDATE - with tested examples:**

- **Add** JDNI name binding `java:global/a`:

```
/subsystem=naming/binding=java\:global\/a:add(value=10,binding-type=simple,type=java.lang.Integer)
```

- **Read** existing JDNI name binding `java:global/a`:

```
/subsystem=naming/binding=java\:global\/a:read-resource(include-defaults=true)
```

- **Modify** JDNI name binding value `java:global/a`:

```
/subsystem=naming/binding=java\:global\/a:write-attribute(name=value, value=20)
```

- **Remove** JDNI name binding `java:global/a`:

```
/subsystem=naming/binding=java\:global\/a:remove()
```

**Executing command directly from shell:**

```
./jboss-cli.sh --connect --command="/subsystem=naming/binding=java\:global\/a:read-resource(include-defaults=true)"
```

Answer (score 3):

The question has a lot of views so I'll answer to it. Inspired by @mik response I've figured out that to change value of some JNDI key e.g. `java:jboss/api/key` to newApiKey run [JBoss CLI](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/Admin+Guide#AdminGuide-RunningtheCLI) and execute:

```
connect
/subsystem=naming/binding=java\:jboss\/api\/key/:write-attribute(name=value,value=newApiKey)
```

The change will be immediately visible on server and also stored (updated) in `standalone.xml`so it won't get lost after server restart.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking exactly for how to add or modify a JNDI binding at runtime, but I needed to to do this in a Wildfly 9 domain (cluster) configuration (not standalone), which is pretty much the same configuration as JBoss 7. However, I couldn't figure out a way to effectively apply changes without restarting all servers.

To start with, enter the JBoss command line interface and connect to your server domain controller:

```
./jboss-cli.sh
connect
```

First, you need to find which profile is active on the server group, so as, on the server root */*, enter the following commands:

```
cd server-group=
ls
```

Afterwards, you should enter the only server group shown in the listing command (ls) by typing `cd {{your_server_group_name}}`, then type `ls` again and look for an entry named *profile* to check which one is active. Let's consider *full-ha* as an active profile for our example.

Next, go back to the root configuration folder / by typing `cd ..` and enter the following commands to navigate and view all JNDI bindings available with their current values:

```
cd profile=full-ha/subsystem=naming/binding=
:read-resource(recursive=true)
```

By doing this, you'll be able to see all available JNDI bindings and their attributes, if you want to list only binding names, type `ls` instead of the last command.

In order to modify a binding, type `cd` and the name of the binding listed in the previous command. Let's suppose you want to change the value of a binding named *java:/webservice.url*, then you should enter

```
cd java\:\/webservice.url
```

Notice that is necessary to quote some characters in your binding name such as *: (colon)* and */ (slash)* with a backslash (*\*).

To modify an attribute within this binding you should use the :write-attribute command. In this example, let's suppose you want to modify (or add) an attribute named *"value"* with its content as "this is a value":

```
:write-attribute(name=value,value="this is a value")
```

So as to apply this change, you'll need to restart all servers in the cluster by typing the following command:

```
/server-group={{server-group-name}}:restart-servers
```

If you want to know more commands to add or remove JNDI bindings check this [jboss-cli snippets page](https://github.com/juliojsb/jboss-cli-snippets-compilation#domain-5)

This configuration has been tested successfully in Wildfly 9.0.1